# Is it possible to pass values from a Sub-Dataset To A Sub-Report in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I can't seem to find an answer to this, in the iReport guide or after scouring the Internet for quite a while. So I'll just ask. I have a Field in a Sub-Dataset that I wish to pass to a parameter in a Sub-Report.

Is this possible?

Comment: what is your use case, maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible. sub datasets are bound to a report element that can hold a sub dataset during report run time. They do not provide return values.

Comment: Is there a way around this? Because I need to use the information stored in the Field in the Sub-Dataset, to run another query because it functions as part of the primary key.

Comment: can you describe what you want to achieve with your report? General answer is: move your sub-dataset into a subreport as main dataset and then implement the functionality required there. but again - if you give a more detailed use case a better answer might be possibel.

Comment: Basically, the report has a main query. From this query I will get x number of results. The results then act as a primary key in a following query that will, in turn, produce x-number of results. Then these results will once again, act as a primary key for another query. And so forth. Until I get to the lowest level. From here I will list all the information tied to that final query. And the only way I know how to put more than one query in a report is via sub-datasets. The issue is getting them to see each other, if possible.

Comment: so you have a parent-child hierarchy in your database that you want to put into a report?

Comment: What's the best way to do that?

Comment: please raise a separate question for that.